# ng-init not working if multiple items in angularjs, but working for single item

Tags: angularjs

> I am new to stackoverflow, Sorry if this question is not proper.
>
> I had declared a function in ng-init within the ng-repeat(session) to
>   get the questions length by passing session id.

```
//This is the HTML Part
<tr ng-repeat="session in sessionslist" ng-init='getQuestionsofSession(accessors.getId(session))' >
<td>{{session.name}}</td>
<td>{{session.speakers.length}}</td>
<td><p>{{questions.length}}</p></td>
</tr>

//This is the ANGULAR Part
    $scope.getQuestionsofSession = function(sessionid){
        $http.get('/api/audiencepanel/getquestions/'+sessionid)
            .success(function(data){                
                $scope.questions= data;
            });
    };

//Getting sessions list
$scope.getsessions= function(){
$http.get("api/getsession/"+$stateParams.id).success(function(data){
$scope.sessionslist = data;
});
```

> So if the session length is single, ng-init is working, but sessions
>   length multiple it is not showing any data. $scope.questions is not
>   showing any data
>
> By the way, Session table is different and Question table is
>   different, questions are stored based on session id. So need questions data in session data based on session id
>
> Is there any other way to get this worked?

Comment: Don't use ng-init. It should almost never be used, as documented. Initialize the data needed by the view from your controller directly. BTW, It doesn't make much sense to have a single $scope.questions field, containing the questions of one session, since  you're displaying several sessions.

Comment: Instead of using ng-init loop through the sessionslist and fetch questions

Comment: It is not a good practice to raise a API call for every element inside a ng-repeat. What you are actually looking for?

Comment: @simon modified the question with adding sessionlist code. Can you please add some code to fetch the questions?

Comment: @Aravind Please read my question properly, I want other(Questions) DB table data to be displayed on Session View, I don't have problem with API's

Comment: @JBNizet Can you please explain with sample code?

Comment: you can instead get this in a single request itself when you create a session as a request. Have these response data 
**1.session.id
2.session.name
3.speakers.length
4.questions.length** in one response. which will increase scalability as well

Comment: you get questions but where is that you are using??

Comment: @Kranthi Updated answer

Comment: @Aravind inside ng-repeat of sessions list

Comment: **<td><p>{{questions.length}}</p></td>** this line uses only length ? where are you using your questions?

Comment: I need only that length of questions. It means in a session how may questions are asked @Aravind

Comment: yes. you are not understanding my thing. When you want just the length of  questrions why do you retrieve all questions and then have a count of it? !! This will not be scalable!

Comment: Ok, Please suggest if there is any other way to get the other table data length in ng-repeat?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside each ng repeat we have different scope. So `question` object in `sessionslist[0]` is not same as `sessionslist[1]`

Instead of using init you could do like this

```
$scope.getsessions= function(){
   $http.get("api/getsession/"+$stateParams.id).success(function(data){
   angular.forEach(data, function(value, key){
      $http.get('/api/audiencepanel/getquestions/'+value.id)
            .success(function(data1){                
                value.questions= data1;
            });
   });
   $scope.sessionslist = data;
});
```